# How to write a python regex negative lookaround in which both assertions must be true?

Tags: python, regex

So I'm trying to match all occurrences of a certain abbreviation `XYZ`, but only when they are not surrounded on both sides with parentheses. The strings `XYZ filler text`,`(XYZ filler text)`, and `(Filler text XYZ)` should all match, and the string `(XYZ)` should not match.

The closest I can get is

```
(?<!\()XYZ(?!\))
```

Of course the problem with this is that if either negative assertion matches the whole thing is no longer a match. How should I go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can or (`|`) regex:

```
(?<!\()XYZ|XYZ(?!\))
```

**Example**:

```
import re

lst = ['XYZ filler text', '(XYZ filler text)', '(Filler text XYZ)', '(XYZ)']

for x in lst:
    print(re.search(r'(?<!\()XYZ|XYZ(?!\))', x))
```

which outputs:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='XYZ'>
<re.Match object; span=(1, 4), match='XYZ'>      
<re.Match object; span=(13, 16), match='XYZ'>     
None
```

Comment: That was just what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex #1 or #2
and avoid regex #3

```
Regex1:   XYZ(?!(?<=\(...(?=\))))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    0.53 s,   531.79 ms,   531788 µs
Matches per sec:   846,201


Regex2:   XYZ(?:(?!\))|(?<!\(...))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    0.53 s,   533.03 ms,   533029 µs
Matches per sec:   844,231


Regex3:   (?<!\()XYZ|XYZ(?!\))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   9
Elapsed Time:    1.42 s,   1417.15 ms,   1417151 µs
Matches per sec:   317,538
```